# Is there any cross broswer (IE7-8) supported js file for CSS3 property display:box / display:flexbox?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using **display: flex** option for one of my application. I am lacking of **IE7-8** support for this. Is there any good performance plugin available to support Flex in **IE7-8**?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Flexiejs](http://flexiejs.com)?

Comment: I have seen this. But in IE7 there is some delay to render the things in flex mode. Is there any alternate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use some javascript library like moderninzr and to do fallback for no-flexbox browser using display: table-row , display: table-cell if you have a simple layout.

and use https://github.com/doctyper/flexie (javascript polyfill) in case when you have a real hard layout.